# Android GAE polymorphism in Client side

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, objectify

I am developing an Android application which use Google App Engine (GAE) for his back-end and with few words the situation is that...

On the back-end side (App Engine Java Endpoints Module) I have a few @Entity classes like "Vehicle", "Car" and "SportCar" where "SportCar" is a @Subclass of "Car" and "Car" is a @Subclass of "Vehicle".

```
@Entity
public class Vehicle{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String brand;
}

@Subclass(index = true)
public class Car extends Vehicle{

    private int wheelsNumber;
}

@Subclass(index = true)
public class SportCar extends Car{

    private boolean hasTurbo;
}
```

And one endpoint class "VehicleEndpoint" which contains a method which return a list of Vehicle entities.

```
@Api{name = "vehicleEndpoint", version = "v1", resource = "vehicle", ...}
public class VehicleEndpoint {

@ApiMethod(name = "listVehicles", path = "vehicle", 
           httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
public CollectionResponse<Vehicle> listVehicles(){
     ...
 }
}
```

So, when I call "listVehicle" from the client side (Android app) I received a list of Vehicle objects but don't know which is "Car" and which is "SportCar".
I cannot cast these Vehicle objects to Car or SportCar because the sub-classes are not recognized in the client side, because they are not include in the "VehicleEndpoint" class.

```
List<Vehicle> listVehicle = vehicleEndpoint.listVehicles().execute().getItems();
```

And another thing which I noticed is that on the android side we import the Vehicle class but it is from another package, not the same package which is in the back-end side (Back-end package -> "com.my.example.backend.entity" and Client-side import-> "com.my.example.backend.endpoint.vehicleEndpoint.model.Vehicle").

How we can use the Polymorphism in the client side? (Always want to return the most abstract form or the absolute parent (in this case Vehicle) and than in the client side check what kind it is and use it)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> And another thing which I noticed is that on the android side we
>   import the Vehicle class but it is from another package, not the same
>   package which is in the back-end side (Back-end package ->
>   "com.my.example.backend.entity" and Client-side import->
>   "com.my.example.backend.endpoint.vehicleEndpoint.model.Vehicle").

This is correct behavior in Cloud Endpoints. "com.my.example.backend.entity" is the package of your backend project. When you gradle sync the project, Android Studio creates a client library for you which it conveniently adds as part of your app project. You could actually go get the Cloud Endpoints .jar that Android Studio generates and copy/paste it into another Android project and use your API. That package name "com.my.example.backend.endpoint.vehicleEndpoint.model.Vehicle" is how Cloud Endpoints creates that jar file - which as you can guess, comes from the API annotation you have in your endpoint class. "vehicleEndpoint" e.g.:

```
@Api(
        name = "vehicleEndpoint",
        version = "v1",
        scopes = {
                Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE},
        clientIds = {
                Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID,
                Constants.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,
                Constants.IOS_CLIENT_ID,
                Constants.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID},
        audiences = {
                Constants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE},
        namespace = @ApiNamespace(
                ownerDomain = Constants.API_OWNER,
                ownerName = Constants.API_OWNER,
                packagePath = Constants.API_PACKAGE_PATH
        )
)
```

That's kind of how it works so yes, the package name will be different since the latter is a generated jar file and I guess that is just how it creates it via the API annotation.

As for your casting issue, keep in mind, that when you use an API method in your client such as:

```
List<Vehicle> listVehicle = vehicleEndpoint.listVehicles().execute().getItems();
```

you are getting a Json response that is then finagled back into your model objects. You know this because you can use the API explorer to execute your method and view the response in plain text. Everything you see there is everything you get. Things like casting might not work there. You might have to put an additional field in your Vehicle object to indicate what type it is.

Hope that gave you some insight into how this system works.

Comment: First Thanks for you response. But if for example one of the sub-classes "Car" is not include in the endpoint class "VehicleEndpoint" than we cannot reach it in the client-side, because this sub-class will not be added in the library's package "com.my.example.backend.endpoint.vehicleEndpoint".

Comment: And another thing which I want to add here is I don't think the best approach here is to use entity classes from the back-end directly in the front-end. May be it would be good to create a separate entity classes in the front-end and receive JSON data from the back-end which to parse in these entities in the front-end?